# Display date now in the whole gridview column

Tags: vb.net

I have this code  to fill all column 5 of DataGirdView1 by current date :

```
For M As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1  
    DataGridView1.Rows(M).Cells(5).Value = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")  
Next
```

But now i change DataGridView with GridControl .. but this code does not work correctly

```
For M As Integer = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1  
    GridView1.SetRowCellValue(M, 5, DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
Next
```

But unfortunately GridView1 column 5 is completely empty .. nothing is displayed

Comment: The SetRowCellValue doesn't have an integer as the second parameter.  Looks like a string or a Column object.  Look at the specs.

Comment: Thank you LarsTech .. i tried also like this but always nothing is displayed (   For M As Integer = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1
            GridView1.SetRowCellValue(M, "GridColumn6", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
        Next)

Answer (score 0):

Is the datagridview bound to a datatable ? Then you should make changes to the datatable, and let the datagridview refresh itself.

**Don't touch the datagridview.** There is no reason. Change the underlying data instead.

The only thing you have to do is set the **format** for your data. Make sure you have a column defined as `datetime` in your datatable, that is properly bound to your grid, then update all rows as desired.

Try something like that to set the date format for a column (using the appropriate column index):

```
DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

Or set the datagridview properties directly in the form layout screen. You don't have to do this at run-time.

Better yet, use **column names** instead of indexes. Because the user could drag columns and change the display order. It's not a good idea to rely on indexes.

Store dates as datetime, not as strings. You can format them the way you want.

Comment: Thank you Anonymous .. but i want populate automatically a column (5) of gridview ( Dev Express ) by Current date .. thank you master